# How to (non recursively) measure sizes of all (both hidden and unhidden) folders in a directory?

Tags: disk-usage

I have a parent directory `somedir` containing two child directories `.hiddenDir` and `notHidden`.

I want to non-recursively measure the sizes of **all** child directories in `somedir`.

How can I do this in Unix?

---

#### picture of what I want:

[image]

#### failed attempt:

The following `du` based command only returns the visible directories:

```
du -sh *
```

While

```
du -sh .*
```

only returns the hidden directories.

---

How can I return the sizes of **all** the directories like in the picture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match \* with hidden files inside a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186214/how-to-match-with-hidden-files-inside-a-directory)

Comment: @muru There is also the issue of doing this non-recursively, i.e. avoiding calling `du` on any subdirectories.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not entirely sure that's what OP means by non-recursive. They could well be trying to avoid something like a naïve `find . -type d -exec du -sh {} +`

Comment: @muru I'm also uncertain, but Stéphane might be on the right track.

Answer (score 12):

With GNU `du`:

```
du -hd1
```

(it also reports the disk usage for `.` which will be the sum of the disk usages reported for the subdirectories, and that of the non-directory files in the current directory).

With `zsh` and any `du`:

```
du -sk -- *(/D)
```

(in kibibytes).

In any case, while that doesn't report the disk usage of directories at depth `2` or below and their contents, the disk usage of those are still included in the disk usage reported by for the top level directories (in other word, there *is* recursion).

That's one of the potential meaning of the *size* of a directory. In other words, that's the disk space that would be reclaimed if that directory and its contents were to be removed (assuming the files have no hard links outside those directories, and that their data is not referenced (possibly in part) in other files outside those directories), note that it's generally different from the sum of the apparent size of the files themselves (including directory files) as reported by `ls -l`.

Answer (score 2):

Du takes multiple arguments - in fact the *'s are expanded by your shell before they're given to du.  So this is all you need to do.

```
du -sh * .??*
```

Caveat, this will miss files or directories named with `.` and a single character - for example, a directory called `.a`.

`.??*` is used to skip `.` and `..`, which are links the the current and parent directories.

Comment: This seems to miss any name with a single character after the first dot, e.g. `.a`. It would additionally measure the sizes of all matching directories recursively, not just to the 1st level.

Comment: good point about .a, text updated.  I don't think that you understand what the OP meant about non-recursively though.